# Product shortcode - Removing product title on blog posts and pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

How do I remove the title on WooCommerce products when they are posted as short codes?

[product_page id="99"]

I am getting a double title:

1. on the shortcode product embed
2. on the actual blog post

I would like to disable to title on the shortcode only and keep the title on the blog post, but keeping the title on the shop page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those titles are hooked in **`content_single-product.php`** WooCommerce template file as you can see below:

```
/**
 * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5  // <===  HERE
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
 */
```

To remove the product page titles only from your blog posts and pages, when outputted from a shortcode, you will need to add a condition when removing the title in the **`woocommerce_single_product_summary`** hook.

Here is that functional and tested code:

```
function remove_some_product_titles(){
    if( !is_product() ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_some_product_titles', 4);
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

Comment: That worked! however, my title is being placed next to my thumbnail ( on the products page) is there any possible way to place it above the thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the title action using this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```

Let me know if it worked.